# Is there any filter to disable the total fronted in WordPress

Tags: wp-admin, front-end

I got a requirement (CRM system) and it can be developed using WordPress back-end.

So I don't need front-end 100%.

Is there way to disable the front-end 100%?

Comment: you can make a blank theme with just a fiel "index.php" containing `wp_redirect(admin_url("/"));`

Answer (score 6):

### By Killing WP on non-admin Pages

The below code will determine whether you are on a front-end page or not, and kill WP if you are.

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_function' );

function my_function(){
    if ( ! is_admin() ) wp_die();
}
```

Note that this might also affect AJAX requests ( untested ) so you might want to add `wp_doing_ajax()` to your conditional too.

### By Redirecting the Users to Dashboard

Same as above, you can check if you are on admin and redirect the users to back-end from front-end.

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_function' );

function my_function(){
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( admin_url() );
        exit();
    }
}
```

### By Creating an Empty Theme

Create a blank theme, and only add `index.php` and `style.css` as its content. Now you can activate the theme, and everyone visiting the front-end will be getting a white page.

Comment: You can also return a falsey value from the `template_include` hook.

Comment: Shouldn't it read `wp_safe_redirect( admin_url() );` ?

Comment: @brianjohnhanna Thanks for the note. Corrected now.